# SQL Query to Sum Calculated Field

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table that I've Skill ID and its Capacity against some employee's data. Using IIF I made a calculated field **req_Capacity** using the below query

```sql
SELECT 
    emp_code, 
    Skill_ID,
    Capacity,
    Target_Req,
    iif(capacity > target_req,target_req,capacity) as req_Capicity
FROM [load_Style] 
ORDER by Skill_ID
```

Now I want to calculate the calculated field **req_capacity** to group all the employees having the same skill id and if the sum of that skill is greater than 3000 leave the extra data. for example I have the following fields

```
Skill_ID    Req_Capacity
1             1800
1             1800
2             1000
2             1000
2             1000
2             1500
```

**Required Output**

```
Skill_ID    Req_Capacity
1             1800
1             1200
2             1000
2             1000
2             1000
```

I tried the following query

```
Select Load_Style.Skill_ID,Load_Style.Capacity
From Load_Style
Where load_Style.Capacity=(Select load_Style.Capacity From load_Style Group by load_style.Skill_ID Having SUM(load_style.capacity)<=3000)
```

But it gives an error:

> Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Unclear. What is your input  data and expected output? And do you actually want to group the rows or just get a sum over a particular grouping while still returning all the rows?

Comment: Can't find req_Prod  field...

Comment: Sorry its req_capacity  and not Req_ prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the running total for the capacity in order to compare it with 3000. You get this with `SUM OVER`.

```
select
  emp_code, 
  skill_id,
  capacity,
  case 
    when sum(capacity) over(partition by skill_id order by emp_code) - capacity >= 3000 then
      0
    when sum(capacity) over(partition by skill_id order by emp_code) >= 3000 then
      3000 - (sum(capacity) over(partition by skill_id order by emp_code) - capacity)
    else
      capacity
    end as req_capicity
from load_style
order by skill_id, emp_code;
```

Comment: Thorsten Kettner Thanks for the help. Almost there. Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b823f/1

Comment: Thorsten Kettner Some results are in negative.. If the totals of the capacity of required skills  are with in 3000 limit, the capacity should be the as is in the Req_Capacity column, else it should be adjusted to 3000 limit. Please do look into the link mentioned above. Thanks again for helping out...

Comment: Sorry, I missed a pair of parentheses. I've added them now. Thank you for creating the fiddle. Please see it with my altered query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b823f/2

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner. Thank you for helping out. Was the perfect solution